# How to cache string data to sdcard?

Tags: android

I want to  cache json string to sdcard and retrive this cache data for future using. could anyone help me out

Answer (score 1):

Why to Use SDcard to store the data. You should use SharedPreferences. Its easy and Fast.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to serialize it to a ByteOutputStream and write that on the SD card.